# PSMultiValue in app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, settings.bundle

I have a settings bundle in my app and I want user can edit settings in app. I dont know how to do it with PSMultiValue. How to load the array for the table and how to save it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Wenn you define a **Settings.bundle** the settings will be avialable in the iPhone settings section. It will handling saving and updating for you.

[**Read Implementing Application Preferences**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html)

To get the same settings view within your app you can use [**InAppSettingsKit**](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/).